# Open start form and close all other Forms with Xamarin Crossplatform

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

At the start of my project I open a Dashboard form, each time I am calling other forms with the Navigation.PushAsync. But when the User logs out I want to close all forms and stacks and open my Dashboard again without going back option. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation.PushModalAsync (modalPage);
It will create new navigation stack, thereby back button won't be visible.